# Steps to setup a new sata II SSD drive on my gigabyte motherboard etc

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I'm going to purchase a OCZ SATA II SSD drive. What should I do to setup Windows 7 on it.

Once it is physically installed, are these the right steps?

1. Change BIOS to boot from the SSD drive
2. Insert the Windows 7 CD and boot
3. done!

Is that it?

I want to keep the original Windows 7 installed so I can bootup from that in case I forget something in my new install, is this possible also?  Is there something I need to do so I get a choice of where to boot from?

Incidentally, where is the SATA II connection on my motherboard?

*I'm reading that a SSD SATA II can do around 250 MB/s read/write. What about my Raptor 10K drives?  (Just trying to get a feel for the performance improvement with a SSD).*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect it like a regular harddrive.

BTW, they are all SATA 2.

Comment: what do you mean? there are sata iii ssd drives though?

Comment: You posted sata 2s. . .

Comment: oh I see, I thought you were saying something else sorry. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I meant all your ports there are Sata II's